# Increase maximum requests on chromium for http1.1

Tags: c++, chromium

I am compiling chromium/google-chrome and I am wondering how I can increase the maximum number of requests per domain for http1.1. I want to speed up the number of concurrent requests when accessing the cache. The cache is storing files in http1.1 & I'd like to fetch a large number of files concurrently. Currently the max appears to be 6.

Where is this limit set in the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is here, in ClientSocketPoolManager.
[net/socket/client_socket_pool_manager.cc:52](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:net/socket/client_socket_pool_manager.cc;drc=a2e7773217092436c998a83e66d6ea88a0a8292b;l=52)